# How can I select checkbox in selenium without knowing the value

Tags: java, selenium, checkbox

Thanks to everyone who read this topic.
I'm working on an automatic test of Poker game in selenium.
When testing the change card option. I have no idea how can i select the checkbox.

[image: Here is an screenshot of the element inspection.]

Because the card is randomly drawn from the pool, i can't know the value of that checkbox when coding. I tried to click on the card, but seems not working (There is a text telling what card is changed after selection, and I used thread.sleep to pause the thread and check the automated window)

```
    this.waitForDisplayed(this.indexPage.card1).isEnabled();
    this.indexPage.card1.click();
    this.indexPage.card2.click();
```

And here is where the indexPage.card is defined

```
@FindBy(id = "PlayerCard1")
public WebElement card1;
@FindBy(id = "PlayerCard2")
public WebElement card2;
@FindBy(id = "PlayerCard3")
public WebElement card3;
@FindBy(id = "PlayerCard4")
public WebElement card4;
@FindBy(id = "PlayerCard5")
public WebElement card5;
```

Comment: the check box can be found with xpath like //*[@id="PlayerCard5"]//input. of course there are many ways to achieve that

Comment: You can click it using PlayerCard5 id,

Comment: Thanks for HenningLuther. I used findElementsBy(By.xpath("//*[contains(@id,'PlayerCard1')]//input")) to find that checkbox, and it is clicked!